# Access "find unmatched query" return records which are available both tables when one of the fields is empty

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I am trying to list records from table `N` that do not have a match in table `O`
The result is shown in query `N Without Matching O`

[image]

As one can see on above image, it is returning records which exist in both tables, which it should not.
In above example table `N` and table `O` are identical (copy)

The query is as follows:

```
SELECT N.*
FROM N LEFT JOIN O ON (N.[F8] = O.[F8]) AND (N.[F7] = O.[F7]) AND (N.[F6] = O.[F6]) AND (N.[F5] = O.[F5]) AND (N.[F4] = O.[F4]) AND (N.[F3] = O.[F3]) AND (N.[F2] = O.[F2]) AND (N.[F1] = O.[F1])
WHERE (((O.F1) Is Null));
```

I guess it is because of empty values (e.g. field `F5` in the example above)
Further down the table other fields may be empty as well

**My question is:**
How do I return unmatched records from a table which may contain empty cells

Answer (score 0):

Try using *Nz* on that field (F5):

```sql
SELECT N.*
FROM N LEFT JOIN O ON (N.[F8] = O.[F8]) AND (N.[F7] = O.[F7]) AND (N.[F6] = O.[F6]) AND (Nz(N.[F5]) = Nz(O.[F5])) AND (N.[F4] = O.[F4]) AND (N.[F3] = O.[F3]) AND (N.[F2] = O.[F2]) AND (N.[F1] = O.[F1])
WHERE (((O.F1) Is Null));
```